# Cannot convert a very large number to hex

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following string:
`std::string data{"4a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff000ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff000"}`

I need to extract it as its equivalent hex value:
*4a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff0000004ec00ff000ff004a00f000f00e1887a9900fff000*

when i do the following code it prints *ffffffffffffffff*.
I see the issue is the value is too large to fix in **value** but how do I overcome this?
Is there a way to perhaps put it in a vector bit by bit using a for loop?

```
{
    std::istringstream hex_buffer(data);

    unsigned long long value;

    hex_buffer >> std::hex >> value;

    std::cout << value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already have its hex value. If you need it as an actual number you’ll have to use a library that allows such a big number. What do you want to do with this number?

Comment: A 64-bit `unsigned` integral type has maximum value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.   Although some implementations support an `unsigned long long` type that can support a larger range of values, there is no requirement that they do so.  Your value is many orders of magnitude larger.   To overcome that, you'll need to use dedicated third-party library support for a "big integer" type, or implement your own

Comment: You can put the data into a vector if you think that will help. It all depends on what you want to do with that data once you've converted it. You might be looking for a large integer library, such as GMP, MPIR or I think boost has one now as well.

Answer (score 1):

C++ language uses fixed size integral types. The basic set contains (increasing sizes): `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`. `char` has at least 8 bits, `short` and `int` at least 16, and `long` at least 32.

`long long` is an optional type with at least 64 bits when it exists. But I know no architecture with  an integral type of more that 64 bits, meaning that the larger value can be represented in an `unsigned long long` is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

You can of course define a class able to handle integer values or arbitrary sized, or use a library that can process arbitrary size values like `gmp`, by you cannot expect store a number of more than 64 bits in a 64 bit integer.